# Load images after div is made visible

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, lazy-loading

I have a photo gallery that is built by posts in Wordpress. The gallery is split up into four different categories. When a user navigates to the gallery, the images from a default category show, and the other categories are hidden. Then via jquery, the user can navigate to another category, which hides the current category and images, and shows the new category images.

All of that is working fine, except that the page loads the entire gallery including all four categories worth of images even if the user never visits the other categories.

What I'd like is for the images in other categories to load individually once their category is shown. How can I go about this?

My html setup for one toggle and category:
(The other three are the same, except commissions is replaced with sculptures, etc.)

```
<div class="viewnav gallery-toggle commissions-toggle"> 
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/works-commissions" alt="" /> 
 <div class="mask"> 
 <h3>Commissions</h3> 
     <a href="#" class="info">See More</a> 
 </div> 
 </div>



 <div class="commissions">

 <h2 class="gallery-title">Commissions</h2>

 <?php query_posts('post_type=works_gallery&galleryitems_category=commissions&order=ASC&posts_per_page=24'); ?>

 <div class="gallery-group">

 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


      <div class="view"> 
           <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'gallery-thumbnail')); ?>
           <div class="mask"> 
                <h3><?php the_title();?></h3> 
                <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                <?php $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
                   echo '<a class="info" href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
                   echo 'Enlarge Image';
                   echo '</a>';
                 ?>
           </div> 
      </div>


 <?php endwhile;?><?php endif; ?>

 </div><!--gallery-group-->

 <div class="clearfix"></div>

 </div><!--commissions-->
```

The JQuery for the toggle...

```
     (function($) {  // beginning wordpress function

    $('.commissions, .decanters, .sculptural, .artglass').hide();
    $('.artglass').fadeIn(1000).addClass('active-gallery');

      $(document).ready(function() {

         $('.gallery-toggle').click(function(){
             $('.active-gallery').hide().removeClass('active-gallery');
             return false;
         });
         $('.commissions-toggle').click(function(){
             $('.commissions').fadeIn(1000).addClass('active-gallery');
         });

     });
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. There are about 45 total images among the four categories, so the load is pretty heavy to get the page moving.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate. Search for lazyloading.

Comment: Not really. This is a bit more specific to wordpress as I can't just add the plugin and target an image specifically. It would have to be a dynamic target. If you know how to do that...please chime in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the lazy loading plugin is the right answer, but if you're dead set on detecting what's visible and what's not first, try [jQuery sonar](https://github.com/artzstudio/jQuery-Sonar) (try the [demo](http://www.artzstudio.com/files/jquery-boston-2010/jquery.sonar/examples/jquery.sonar.html)) to detect which galleries are visible and then attach the lazy loader to the galleries that are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I felt like I should update this. I did find the answer via a [Lazy Load plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/) for Wordpress. It uses the jQuery Lazy Load as well as jQuery Sonar which was mentioned by mdelorey. Works brilliantly with no setup. Thanks all.